# Name folder based on file name using regex in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to name a folder based on a file name, using regex in powershell.

The name looks something like this `tester2-2013-14-10.txt`.

With that file name being said, I want to create a folder named `tester2`. It will do this for all files in a directory. Basically the regex needs to read up until the first '-', then ignore all other characters after that. It

All regular expressions that I am trying have not worked to do such a things.

Here is the regex I am trying to use `(\w+)\.txt`.

And here it is when I try and implement it:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where{$_.Name -match '(\w+)\.txt'} | ForEach-Object{
  md $matches[1]}
```

Along with other variations of this type of thing.

It appears that when I run a file name against this regex, it is using the end of the string. Such as in the case of `tester2-2013-14-10.txt`. The folder name that is being created is called `10` instead of `Tester2`.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: what if the file is not in current folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following regex

```
^(\w+)-.*\.txt
```

Refer to [regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/qI2pS3) for validation and explanation.

**Short Description**

`^` matches start of the line or string. It will ensure that match should be at the starting of a line.

Hence `^(\w+)` will match the first word in the file name. Then it has to be followed by `-` and any characters until `.txt`

**What's wrong with your regex?**

`(\w+)\.txt` will match a word `(\w+)` *immediately* followed by `.txt`.

Hence you are getting last word instead of the first word.

Comment: You sir are magical, thank you. Could I bother to ask for an explanation of what I was doing wrong, and how it compares to yours.

I didn't include the '-' at the end of my regex because I assumed the '\w+' would read until the non-word character.

Comment: @JohnnyWhisman check my edits. provided regex demo also explains it well. you can play around there and explore more.

Comment: @JohnnyWhisman `\w` matches a word character, and a word character is broadly defined as A through Z (also a through z), 0 through 9 and the underscore character, _. Hence, `\w` doesn't match hyphens/dashes, `-`.

Comment: @jkshah thank you for this. And for supplying me with the regex demo, it is very helpful.